# Move matplotlib Polar Plot Label Values

Tags: python, matplotlib

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eq8pp.png

I have this polar plot and I want to move the latitude labels so that they are below the lines.

Anything I can find online doesn't work, does anyone have a method?

Here is my code:

```
ax = pyplot.subplot(polar=True)
ax.plot(data blah blah blah)
#rotate map
ax.set_theta_offset((3*math.pi)/2)
#set labels
ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([0, (math.pi)/2, (math.pi), (3*math.pi)/2])
ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([-50, -60, -70, -80])
ax.set_xticklabels(["0 MLT", "6", "12", "18"])
#change colors of axis to gray
ax.xaxis.grid(True,color='dimgray',linestyle='-', linewidth = 1)
ax.yaxis.grid(True,color='dimgray',linestyle='-', linewidth = 1)
#margins to zero
pyplot.margins(0)
```

Comment: Please elaborate. question is fully clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to move the tick labels by adding horizontal_alignment to ax.set_yticklabels.

Example with the code I posted above:

```
ax.set_yticklabels(["-50", "-60", "-70", "-80"], horizontalalignment = "left", verticalalignment = "top")
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the [official reference](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/polar_demo.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-polar-demo-py), but your code didn't display it well. I will suggest another way.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

ax = plt.subplot(polar=True)

size = 100
x = np.linspace(0, 2 * np.pi, size)
y = np.sin(6*x) + np.random.normal(0, 0.08, (size))

ax.plot(x,y)
#rotate map
ax.set_theta_offset((3*math.pi)/2)

ax.set_thetalim([np.pi, 0])
# angle is degree measure
ax.set_thetagrids([0.0, 90.0, 180.0, 270.0, 360.0], 
                  labels=["0 MLT", "6", "12", "18"], fontsize=12)
ax.set_rlim([-3.0, 3.0])
# angle is degree measure
ax.set_rgrids(np.arange(-3, 3.01, 1), labels=[-50, -60, -70, -80], fontsize=12, angle=180)

#change colors of axis to gray
ax.xaxis.grid(True,color='dimgray',linestyle='-', linewidth = 1)
ax.yaxis.grid(True,color='dimgray',linestyle='-', linewidth = 1)
#margins to zero
plt.margins(0)
```

[image]